# Error while compiling qobject in dll for qlibrary

Tags: c++, qt, dll, qmake

I write some core for loading *.dll files dynamically. As primary instrument I use Qt 5.12 enterprise edition. This dll have to download other qobject inherited class via QLibrary for connecting and using it in core program, for connecting it via signals/slots. But when compiling dll, thatnshould be downloaded via qlibrary, I receved a error message "Undefined reference for vtable, driver interface ", I saw the same questions on stack overflow, but solutions in them was as try to clean and rebuild project, doesn't work for me. Maybe I should include other moc files, but which? I use qmake as build system. All pure virtual methods are redefined in inherited class. listing below.

```
#ifndef DRIVER101104_H
#define DRIVER101104_H

#include "driver101-104_global.h"
#include "driverinterface.h"
#include "protocol101104wrapper.h"
#include <QObject>
#include <functional>
#include <QHash>

class Driver101104 : public DriverInterface
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Driver101104();
    virtual ~Driver101104();
    // DriverInterface interface
public:
    void setMessageAsString(const QString &_message);
    QString getMessageAsString();
    void initializeChannel(const QJsonObject& _parameters);
    bool downloadTagsModel(const QHash<QString, std::shared_ptr<TagModel> > &_tagModels);
    void setCallBackFunction(const QString &_nameOfCallBack, std::function<void (const QString &)> _callback);
private:
    protocol101104Wrapper wrapper;
};

extern "C"{
    DRIVER101104SHARED_EXPORT DriverInterface* createDriverClass(){
        return new Driver101104();
    }
}

#endif // DRIVER101104_H
```

```
#ifndef DRIVERINTERFACE_H
#define DRIVERINTERFACE_H
#include <QHash>
#include <memory>
#include <functional>
#include <QJsonObject>
#include <QObject>

class TagModel;

class DriverInterface : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    DriverInterface() : QObject(nullptr){

    }

    virtual ~DriverInterface() {

    }
    /*This methods are for external type of driver connection!
     * All other logick have to be In usual cases.*/
    virtual void setMessageAsString(const QString& _message) = 0;
    virtual QString getMessageAsString() = 0;

    /*This method for type of external LinkAgent and external driver!*/
    virtual void initializeChannel(const QJsonObject& _parameters) = 0;
    virtual void setCallBackFunction(const QString& _nameOfCallBack,
                                     std::function<void (const QString& _message)> _callBack) = 0;


    /*Usual type of working, Device download tags model into it's own storage
     * and serialize or deserialize it.*/
    virtual bool downloadTagsModel(const QHash<QString, std::shared_ptr<TagModel>>& _tagModels) = 0;
};

    #endif // DRIVERINTERFACE_H
```

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2019-10-14T15:08:10
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       -= gui

TARGET = Driver101-104
TEMPLATE = lib

DEFINES += DRIVER101104_LIBRARY

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any feature of Qt which has been marked as deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if you use deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

include(LibHeaders.pri)
include(LibSources.pri)

CONFIG += c++11

SOURCES += \
        callbacknames.cpp \
        driver101104.cpp \
        protocol101104wrapper.cpp \
        servicenames.cpp

HEADERS += \
        callbacknames.h \
        driver101104.h \
        driver101-104_global.h  \
        driverinterface.h \
        enums.h \
        protocol101104wrapper.h \
        servicenames.h

unix {
    target.path = /usr/lib
    INSTALLS += target
}
```

```
#include "driver101104.h"

Driver101104::Driver101104():DriverInterface()
{
}

Driver101104::~Driver101104()
{

}

void Driver101104::setMessageAsString(const QString &_message)
{

}

QString Driver101104::getMessageAsString()
{

}

/**
 * @brief Driver101104::initializeChannel
 * @param _parameters
 */
void Driver101104::initializeChannel(const QJsonObject& _parameters)
{
   wrapper.channelInitializer(_parameters);
}


/**
 * @brief Driver101104::downloadTagsModel
 * Here should be something that return code
 * of error for this program
 * @param _tagModels
 * @return
 */

bool Driver101104::downloadTagsModel(const QHash<QString, std::shared_ptr<TagModel> >& _tagModels)
{
    return true;
}

void Driver101104::setCallBackFunction(const QString &_nameOfFunction, std::function<void (const QString&)> _callback)
{
    wrapper.setCallBackFunction(_nameOfFunction,_callback);
}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a look at this article as your post seems to be rather long and it's probably not necessary to have so much code in it : https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hello, interesting artilce, but never the less, all I have writen  are necessary for understanding the problem. It's not trivial to solve this problem, if it was I would solve it by my self.

Comment: Please correct your question, currently is hard to understand. And please provide  all the code needed labeled with file names, that when compiled produces the same errors that you are asking for help. Currently, your project.pro mentions files that you don't provide, and in "driver101104.h" you #include "driver101-104_global.h" and "protocol101104wrapper.h" that you don't provide either. So, I am unable to reproduce your compilation problem, because the compiler produces much many other errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer for this problem, I rewrote class of driverInterface and driver01104, after it, all complied correct. Library loaded and work correct. Only connection with signals and slots doesn't work.

```
    #ifndef DRIVER101104_H
#define DRIVER101104_H

#include <QObject>
#include <functional>
#include <QHash>
#include "driver101-104_global.h"
#include "protocol101104wrapper.h"
#include "driverinterface.h"

class DRIVER101104SHARED_EXPORT Driver101104 : public DriverInterface
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Driver101104(QObject* parent = nullptr);
    virtual ~Driver101104();

public:
    void initializeChannel(const QJsonObject &_parameters);
    void setCallBackFunction(const QString &_nameOfCallBack,
                             std::function<void (const QString &)> _callback);
    bool downloadTagsModel(const QHash<QString,
                           std::shared_ptr<TagModel> > &_tagModels);
    void setMessageAsString(const QString &_message);
    QString getMessageAsString();


private:
    protocol101104Wrapper* wrapper;
};

extern "C"{
    DRIVER101104SHARED_EXPORT DriverInterface* createDriverClass();
}

#endif // DRIVER101104_H



#ifndef DRIVERINTERFACE_H
#define DRIVERINTERFACE_H

#include <QObject>
#include <functional>
#include <QString>
#include <memory>
#include <QHash>
#include <QJsonObject>

class TagModel;

class DriverInterface : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:

    DriverInterface(QObject* parent = nullptr): QObject(parent){

    }

    virtual ~DriverInterface(){

    }

    virtual void setMessageAsString(const QString& _message) = 0;
    virtual void initializeChannel(const QJsonObject& _parameters) = 0;
    virtual void setCallBackFunction(const QString &_nameOfCallBack,
                             std::function<void (const QString &)> _callback) = 0;
    virtual bool downloadTagsModel(const QHash<QString,
                           std::shared_ptr<TagModel> >& _tagModels) = 0;
    virtual QString getMessageAsString() = 0;

signals:
    void callBackMessage(QJsonObject _message);

};

#endif // DRIVERINTERFACE_H
```